# How to check if a integer input is a string without valueError

Tags: python-3.x

```
while True:
    Check = isinstance(Age, str)
    Age = (int(input("Ok, How old are you: ")))
    if 100 <= Age:
        print("try again")
    if Check == True:
        print("try again")
    else:
        break
```

I'm trying to cause it to loop back through if the input is a string while printing "try again", but when I do this, it causes a ValueError

Comment: Probably you mean the second `if` to be `elif`.

Comment: please, attach the stacktrace

Comment: int(input('...')) will fall if user will enter string that is not an integer

Answer (score 1):

If you execute your code, the first error will be `NameError`, because you are using it before the input.

But if you want to check if the user input is a number without ValueError, you can use `isdigit` function. With a little modifications, you can achieve what you are trying to do with:

```
while True:
    age = input("Ok, How old are you: ")

    if age.isdigit() and int(age) <= 100:
        break

    print("try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes in before your `if` check. You're casting the input to `int` which may not be possible, hence you're getting a `ValueError`.

You need to instead do something like:

```py
while True:
    age = input("How old are you?")
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print('try again')
        continue
    if age >= 100:
        print('try again')
        continue
    break
```